# Convert part of row to columns

Tags: python, awk, rows, unpivot

I have a file with an input :

```
rownum,identifier,items_in_list
1,"ABC",{(123),(345),(69),(95),(90),(83),(3A)}
```

with expected output as :

```
rownum,identifier,items_in_list
1,"ABC",123
1,"ABC",345
1,"ABC",69
1,"ABC",95
1,"ABC",90
1,"ABC",83
1,"ABC",3A
```

I tried using "awk" but it was for turning all items in a column to rows, but mine just needs some columns to rows..

My Code:

```
echo "1,"ABC",{(123),(345),(69),(95),(90),(83),(3A)}" | awk -vRS="{" 'NF'
```

but this converts to:

```
1,ABC,
(123),(345),(69),(95),(90),(83),(3A)}
```

Update:

All of your commands work fine, but for one small glitch sorry being a newbie I can vote only one as a answer.

Thank You! but I am having trouble if the rows dont have multiple numbers and have just one.. eg, in this format:

Input

```
1,33262,"ABC",{(64)} 
1,33263,"ABC",{(66),(57)}
```

Actual Output:

```
1,33262,SOME_FIELD_NAME 
1,33262,64 
1,33263,SOME_FIELD_NAME 
1,33262,65,66
```

Required Output:

```
1,33262,SOME_FIELD_NAME,64 
1,33263,SOME_FIELD_NAME,65
1,33263,SOME_FIELD_NAME,66
```

Update:

"Actual Output" of code suggested by Jotne: awk -F, '{a=$1","$2;gsub(/[{()}]/,"");for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) print a","$i}' file.

Sorry my input has 2 leading fields sometimes and 3-10 leading fields some other times, but the row that we want to convert to column always begins with '{' , individual numbers are enclosed in '()' and end of the row is denoted by '}'. Jotne's code works fine for 2 leading fields but fails for 3 leading fields. Can someone suggest a generic way to parse the fields?

Comment: "Actual Output" of what? Where did "ABC" go? Where did "SOME_FIELD_NAME" come from? Why does your new input have 3 leading fields when your original had 2? THINK about what question you really want to ask and then edit your question to state it correctly with accurate examples and then some of us may take a second look and try again to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way with `awk`

```
awk -F, '{a=$1","$2;gsub(/[{()}]/,"");for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) print a","$i}' file
1,"ABC",123
1,"ABC",345
1,"ABC",69
1,"ABC",95
1,"ABC",90
1,"ABC",83
1,"ABC",3A
```

Using `RS`

```
awk -vRS=, '{gsub(/[{()}]/,"")} NR==1 {a=$1;next} NR==2 {a=a","$1;next} {print a","$1}' file
1,"ABC",123
1,"ABC",345
1,"ABC",69
1,"ABC",95
1,"ABC",90
1,"ABC",83
1,"ABC",3A
```

Comment: Thank You! but I am having trouble if the rows dont have multiple numbers and have just one.. eg, in this format:                                                                                             Input           1,33262,"ABC",{(64)}
Actual Output:                                                         1,33262,SOME_FIELD_NAME
1,33262,64                                                                                     Required Output: 1,33262,SOME_FIELD_NAME,64

Comment: Can you update your original post.  Its not possible to read data within the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a Python solution:

```
input = '1,"ABC",{(123),(345),(69),(95),(90),(83),(3A)}'
for extra_char in '{}()"':
    input = input.replace(extra_char, '')
input_elems = input.split(',')
rownum, identifier = input_elems[0:2]
for item in input_elems[2:]:
    print rownum, identifier, item
```

Answer (score 0):

Python-based solution:

```
import csv
import re

data = ['rownum,identifier,items_in_list',
        '1,"ABC",{(123),(345),(69),(95),(90),(83),(3A)}']

reader = csv.reader(data)  # change data to open(filename, 'rb')
pat = r'{*\(([0-9a-fA-F]+)\)}*'
next(reader)
for row in reader:
    for elem in row[2:]:
        mat = re.search(pat, elem).group(1)
        print(','.join([row[0], '"{}"'.format(row[1]), mat]))
```

Output:

```
1,"ABC",123
1,"ABC",345
1,"ABC",69
1,"ABC",95
1,"ABC",90
1,"ABC",83
1,"ABC",3A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/)./,ORS); gsub(/(^[^(]+)?[(]/,$1 OFS $2 OFS); printf "%s",$0}' file
1,"ABC",123
1,"ABC",345
1,"ABC",69
1,"ABC",95
1,"ABC",90
1,"ABC",83
1,"ABC",3A
```